# TypeError: this.state.monsters.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am Facing the problem like TypeError: this.state.monsters.map is not a function.I Have given this.state ={monsters:[]}  After giving the state like above still i am facing that map is not a function....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
 constructor (){
   super ()
   this.state = {
     monsters : []
   };
 }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(response => response.json)
   .then(users => this.setState({monsters : users}))
}

  render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.state.monsters.map(monster =>(
       <h1 key={monster.id} > {monster.name} </h1>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is it possible that this.state.monsters is getting clobbered by the fetch call in componentDidMount? If you see an error in the console, I'd recommend clicking through to the line of code, adding a breakpoint, and looking at the Closure panel. This is the name in Chrome of the panel that allows you to see the value of variables when a breakpoint is activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inovke `response.json`

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json()) // added parentheses
    .then(monsters => this.setState({ monsters }))
}
```